# Baking light into material not working

Tags: lighting, texture-baking, baking

I'm trying to bake several light points into my texture to export to unity, but it's not working and I have no idea what could the problem be. It's a model of a hand that it's supposed to be looked at from the inside of the model. Whenever I try to bake the lighting into the texture it comes out as completely black. I'm really lost on this one, I would really appreciate some help (I can also share my file with anyone). This is the lighting I'm trying to bake:

[image]